# Returned data by Curl in PHP is cut off

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I'm trying to call a webservice with the Curl extension of PHP. Most of the time, the result from the webservice is cut off at exactly 4000 bytes, but not always.
This is not the case if I use other tools or the Curl commandline tool to call the webservice, so the problem can be confined to php_curl.

I'm doing the following:

> ```
>     $fh = fopen($outfilename, "w");
>     $c = curl_init();
>     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
>     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);
>     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $my_request_xml_data);
>     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type" => "text/xml"));
>     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 50);
>     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
>     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
>     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1);
>     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
>     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
>     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
>     $ret = curl_exec($c);
> // if $ret is false some error handling comes here...
>     curl_close($c);
>     fclose($fh);
> ```

Any ideas?

(I'm using PHP 5.5.30 and/or 7.0.10, same problems in both versions)

Comment: the curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); was only for debugging reasons and the result size is 4000 + sizeof(headerdata).

Comment: How big is `$my_request_xml_data`?

Comment: It's about 12kb. The sending process seems to work as the webserver does not return an error. It seems to deliver a correct answer but it's cut off. Sometimes (seldom) it works and it always works with other tools. The input data is always the same.